# You currently do not have a developer account in QBO

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to obtain my production keys for my QBO app following the steps in this link
[here](https://blogs.intuit.com/blog/2022/02/14/updated-process-to-get-production-keys/)

However, when I try to start the "App Assessment Questionnaire", I get the error message below:

> You currently do not have a developer account, please click here to complete setting up your developer account. Once that is complete you will be able to access the help pages.

This is what I see, and I DO have a developer account. It won't let me continue.

Please help!

[image]

**UPDATE**

I see this error in the address bar:

> ErrorCode=ERROR_CREATING_USER&ErrorDescription=License+Limit+Exceeded

**UPDATE #2**

I tried creating a brand new account, a new app, on a different PC and the same thing happened. So this is not a cache issue.

**UPDATE #3**

Created 2 support tickets for this issue

- #[00114423](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/case/5004R00001owxn6QAA/app-assessment-questionnaire-error)
- #[00114415](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/case/5004R00001owxn6QAA/app-assessment-questionnaire-error)

I had to use a different account to access the help site
https://help.developer.intuit.com

Comment: sounds like a question for intuit support

Comment: I can't even log in to intuit developer support. I get the same error message about the license limit

Comment: Did anyone ever find a way to resolve this? I have the same issue and am also unable to even open a support ticket with them (seemingly because of the same Salesforce issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed. I tried running the questionaire and it worked.

Comment: I am having the same issue today. Maybe it's intermittent or only affecting some users.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same issue since Friday (02/18) and spent hours to figure out what's the problem.

- tried from different browsers and different IP addresses
- made a brand new developer account to test with it
- had a 1+ hour chat session with QB support (but not developer support)
- sent an email to an address received from the chat assistant
- sent a feedback at https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/AppAssess

According to the browser's developer tools:

- the Start questionnaire button opens this URL:
  https://developers.intuit.com/app/developer/appdetail/prod/questionnaire?appId=xxxxx:UUID_of_app
- then it redirects to:
  https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/yyyyyyyyyyy/Intuit_Enterprise?community=https://help.developer.intuit.com
- finally, SSO to salesforce fails and it redirects back to:
  https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/qbms-payments/hosted-paypage/faqs/help-redirect?**ErrorCode=ERROR_CREATING_USER&ErrorDescription=License+Limit+Exceeded**+-+Customer+Community+Login&ProviderId=xxxxxx&startURL=%2Fs%2Fquestionnaire%3Fapp%yyyyyyyyyyyyy

So, it seems to be, QB have reached a license limit at salesforce, which prevents new logins to create and the questionnaire from to load.

And the funny part is: the same thing happens, when I tried to create a support ticket and used the "Ask a question" button at https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/

Which means, I can't start the questionnaire and can't start a ticket about the error either.

I guess, if QB developer accounts whom created support tickets previously or started the questionnarie before the license limit has been reached, they have have a SSO login account at salesforce and able to fill in the form or start new support tickets, but others are stuck because of the license limit.

If somebody have a working QB developer account and able to start a support ticket, please do it, and link this page in it.

Or maybe, we should contact salesforce support to let QB know about the license limit.
I'll give it a try.

Comment: please keep me posted if you find anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been having this problem the last several days and had the same lack of success with QB support. The URL callback error I see is:

> ErrorCode=REGISTRATION_HANDLER_ERROR&ErrorDescription=Please+sign+the+terms+of+service+before+you+login+to+community

I don't see anywhere I can sign a TOS in my account page - it's possible that in fact QBO hasn't signed a TOS with Salesforce. What a joke.